# Polymer polymer-micro causing error

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have just setup a fresh install of Laravel with Polymer.

I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <core-icon src="//www.polymer-project.org/images/icons/android.svg"></core-icon>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function - polymer-micro.html:63

There are few articles online regarding this error and I have tried:

```
bower update
bower cache clean
```

To no effect.

How do I fix this?

My bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~1.0.5",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#~1.0.1",
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#~1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you trying to use here? You have tagged this as polymer-1.0 but you are using the `core` element set which in version 1.0 have become `iron` elements.

Comment: I have added my bower.json to an edit. I want to use the latest one. Won't Polymer work without core elements?

Comment: The `core` element were renamed to `iron` elements for the 1.0 release. You can see the iron elements in the catalog [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=iron-elements). You will want to use the `iron-icon` element. A demo of it can be found [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icon)

Comment: What is the alternative for core-header-panel? It seems a lot of stuff is out of date with no documentation about all the changes :s

Comment: That would now be a `paper-header-panel`. The [polymer blog](https://blog.polymer-project.org/) details some changes. Most of the elements names have renamed the same or are similar (i.e core is now iron). Some elements from 0.5 have either not been ported to 1.0 for a reason or are still waiting to be ported.

Comment: Just a pro-tip, avoid using `~` in your `bower.json`, as you're likely to suffer from massive bit-rot, and API incompatibility. Use `^` instead so everytime you update, you're always synced with the latest version of each component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <core-icon src="//www.polymer-project.org/images/icons/android.svg"></core-icon>
    </body>
</html>
```

add

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question at all?